# "go build" multiple programs in one folder

Tags: go, build

I have `functions/hello.go` file

Running `go build` results in creating new binary file `functions` inside the same directory.

I'd like to have two source files in `functions` directory: `hello.go` and `hello2.go` and be able to run `go build` which results in two binary files: `hello` and `hello2`.

How to achieve this?

Comment: this means 2 main func in one package which is not possible

Comment: @danicheeta are there any other options to get multiple binary files into one location with single command?

Comment: Please start with https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go packages are scoped per directory. This means you can have only one package, and thus, at most one 'main' package, in a single directory. What you're trying to do simply isn't possible<sup>*</sup>.

You'll need to create subdirectories instead:

```
functions/hello/hello.go
functions/hello2/hello2.go
```

Then you can build them thus:

```
go build functions/...
```

<sup>*</sup> Technically speaking, you *can* accomplish the organization you want, by completely abusing the go tool chain, and specifying the specific go packages to compile, which takes precedence over the other files in the directory. This will only work on the tiniest of programs (basically, a program contained within a single .go file, or a small, manageable number of .go files) This would require multiple commands, and moreover this should *NEVER BE DONE*, so I'm not even going to explain how it could be done. Simply: *NEVER DO THIS!*

Answer (score 1):

you can have 2 seperate package, both with `main` func, then issue this command in both directories:
`GOBIN={compiled-dir} go install`

Comment: `go build -o` is a cleaner solution than `GOBIN=... go install`.